# In Software Update under macOS Monterey 12.6.1, why does the macOS Ventura 13.0 upgrade have a plain icon and a nonfunctional "More Info..." link?

Tags: macos, software-update, ventura

I recently updated an M1 Apple Mac system from macOS Monterey 12.6 (most likely) to 12.6.1. The Software Update window offered the option to upgrade the system to macOS Ventura 13.0, but I went with updating the system to macOS 12.6.1. There was also an update for the Safari Web browser, and I also selected that update. After at least one of the updates was downloaded, there was a period of time where the system was preparing the update or updates and during that time there was Internet connection activity from the system. In the end, the system was updated to macOS 12.6.1.

Yesterday, on this Apple Mac, I opened Software Update shortly after booting up the system and logging in (from what I remember.) It is possible that I opened Software Update by choosing About This Mac from the Apple menu and then clicking the Software Update... button in the About window. Software Update loaded, and from what I remember, at some point, it indicated that macOS Ventura was available. In addition, to the left of the macOS Ventura 13.0 text, there was a round orange and yellow icon, and underneath the macOS Ventura 13.0 text, likely in addition to information about the version and size (in GB) of the upgrade, there was text that said "More Info..." or perhaps just "More Info". Clicking this text opened a Web browser which loaded a page at the Apple Web site about the macOS Ventura software.

However, when I open Software Update, what is always shown (with the exception of the previously mentioned occasion) is the macOS Ventura 13.0 text and to the left of the text is a more plain icon, like a round shape with "mac OS" on it. In addition, though there is "More Info..." text, clicking this text does not do anything. Sometimes, the arrow cursor changes into a hand-shaped cursor when placed over the "More Info..." text. On a previous occasion, it may have happened where the icon to the left of the macOS Ventura 13.0 text was momentarily shown as being orange and yellow. Also, it may have happened where the area of the Software Update window where the macOS Ventura 13.0 text and the icon and the "More Info..." text are displayed has flashed, as if something different was very momentarily displayed.

(An update on the previous paragraph: I opened Software Update and after checking for updates, it displayed an orange and yellow icon to the left of the macOS Ventura 13.0 text for maybe a second or somewhat less than a second before it displayed the plain round icon instead.)

Does anyone know what is causing the plain icon and the nonfunctioning "More Info..." text for the macOS Ventura 13.0 upgrade that is offered in Software Update?

Comment: Could use a screenshot to clarify what you're seeing, but in general, Apple treats major new versions in a different manner from point updates.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this on my device. It is likely a misconfiguration on Apple's software system.

One potential cause, if your system shares this with mine - is any intermediate software update servers. If you're at a school or on a workplace network, they may intercept Apple Software Update to allow updates to be cached and save them bandwidth.

Either way, and regardless, there is no concern here.

Comment: I also saw this before I upgraded.